# Access Denied in JQuery.1.4 hosted by Google or my own domain?

Tags: php, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on a website for a client and I'm getting a strange error in Internet Explorers of all ages.

The site loads with no problems except for a permission denied error inside my JQuery. Stranger still, the error occurs even hosted on my own domain OR if its hosted by Google. At the moment its hosted by me.

The dev site is: http://www.rawfirepits.co.uk. If someone can spot what's inevitably an obvious problem, that would be appreciated!

Thank-you!

Andy

P.S. The internet explorer debugger comes up with this line in the JQuery that it doesn't like!

> e.username?x.open(n,e.url,e.async,e.username,e.password):x.open(n,e.url,e.async);

(Line 123, char 357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I'm not doing the work for you, but it sounds like a domain problem:

http://www.example.com/dir/page.html    **Success** Same protocol and host
http://www.example.com/dir2/other.html  **Success** Same protocol and host
http://www.example.com:81/dir2/other.html   **Failure** Same protocol - different port
https://www.example.com/dir2/other.html **Failure** Different protocol
http://en.example.com/dir2/other.html   **Failure** Different host
http://example.com/dir2/other.html  **Failure** Different host (exact match required)
http://v2.www.example.com/dir2/other.html   **Failure** Different host (exact match required)

make sure you don't create a cross-domain call in an iFrame or ajax call.

Comment: Thank-you for that list of do's and don'ts. I've checked past my list and my javascript looks like this: <script src="http://www.rawfirepits.co.uk/javascripts/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and my web address is: http://www.rawfirepits.co.uk - so, surely thats a pass!? (Ignore the fact this comments box removes www., it is there, honest!)

Answer (score 0):

Ah! One of my many JavaScript which was utilizing JQuery had a form action value pointing to a different domain, this seemed to be the root cause of the problem and is now solved!

So, note to all, make sure your JavaScript themselves do not have links pointing to a different domain!